# loop over array and based on date show title

Tags: jquery

I am trying to loop over some dates and based on the date only show the `$titles` if it has the date for today. I suspect my if statement is off but I am not sure. Checking the console I get no errors. No titles gets returned too in the console. So I am not sure where to go from here?

```
$('<ul></ul>').insertAfter('h1');
    $.get('http://website.com/rss.php', function(data) {
        var $items = $(data).find('item');
        $items.each(function() {
            var $item = $(this);
            var $pubdate = $item.find('pubDate').text();

            if ($pubdate == "Mon, 14 May 2012 19:40:40 UT") {
                var $title = $item.find('title').text();
                var html = '<li>' + $title + '</li>';
                $(html).appendTo('ul');
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: @powtac Nothing gets returned to the console. No content or errors.

Comment: I fixed it. see answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$pubdate` string includes the newline, so you must include it in your comparison:

```
if ($pubdate == "Mon, 14 May 2012 19:40:40 UT\n")
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/Y5dNc/6/

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead, it is more failsave.

```
if ($pubdate.trim().match(/Mon, 14 May 2012 19:40:40 UT/)) {
    console.log("yes");
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/8q6Pe/